# Best table name instead of "user", if the DB doesn't like that

Tags: terminology

Yes, I know, it is possible to quote the name of the table, but it is sometimes improper.

If there is no alternative, I name this table as "users", although this semantically unneeded plural makes things a little bit inconsistent.

What alternative solutions do exist?

Comment: I prefer to name my tables in the plural if they are supposed to contain more than one "thing".

Comment: Religious war. A bag for apples is still the "apple bag" not the "apples bag"! You might have a nuclear power plant with an IT system with a table called Catastrophic_Meltdown - a table in which hopefully you would never want any records at all!

Comment: I'm in favour of singular names for tables but using plural names has one advantage: we can use `Groups`, `Users`, `Orders`, `Plans`, `Likes`, `Keys`, etc (which unfortunately we can't if we stick to singular.)

Comment: @Vérace that would be AppleBagItems and CatastrophicMeltdownEvents. I find it to be always possible to use plural names.

Comment: I favour collective nouns for table names. The Customers table models a collection of customer entities. The Personnel table is a collection of employee entities. "User" seems too generic, however. What entity is this table actually modelling?

Comment: `UserData` would be one of the best options. Please, don't use languages other than English and of course, don't make a password out of your table name (something like Y00ZER would be the worst)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use non-English words, for me usaideoir (Irish) or utilisateur (French). Pehaps for you, benutzer (German), felhasznalo (Hungarian) or korisnik (Croatian)? Accents have been removed. I know it adds to the typing, but it can save time when you want to port to a new db - no quotes. Anyway, quoting identifiers is a notorious source of errors.

Tables (also columns) can also generally have a comment associated with them which can be used to indicate any departures from a standard (i.e. in this case the English language!).

Comment: This could be a problem when working with developers who know nothing about Irish/French/German/Hunrarian/Croation. The Irish and French I could probably guess at, but the Croatian one I'd never guess what it was just by looking at the name.

Comment: Big gratulation to your language estimation technology! :-)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - COMMENT ON TABLE... beats the bugs with "Field Name Unknown: User" (time wasted checking field exists...). Peter - Thanks!

Comment: yeah this definitely won't confuse anyone.

Comment: Tables (also columns) can also generally have a comment associated with them which can be used to indicate any departures from a standard (i.e. in this case the English language!).

Answer (score 4):

Put some context in the name. If the table is for a CMS, maybe name the table `CMS_USER`. If it's a reporting tool, `REPORT_USER`. You could include the application name in it, as `${applicationName}_USER`. Failing those, would just `APPLICATION_USER` be OK? I did once see a table named `UZER`, along the tradition of naming a variable representing a class as `clazz`, but I'm not too fond of that one. You could do something like `U5ER`, since a "5" sort of looks like an "S". Or you could just go totally phonetic and name the table something like `YOOZER`.

Answer (score 3):

For table names, you can prefix your tables with t, tbl, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE schema.tuser
```

Personally, I like to make my tables plural, as if it's a *table of users*, rather than a *table of user*.

```
CREATE TABLE schema.users
```

If you don't like either of those options, you can always be more descriptive when making your tables. What kind of users are they? What is the database for?

```
CREATE TABLE schema.appusers
```